# How to store the Huffman codes with low volume in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, huffman-code

What is the best way to store a Huffman code in MATLAB?
for example:

```
      letters = [1:6]; % Distinct symbols the data source can produce
      p = [.5 .125 .125 .125 .0625 .0625]; % Probability distribution

      [dict,avglen] = huffmandict(letters,p); % Get Huffman code.
      sig  = randsrc(1,20,[letters; p]) % Create data using p.
      comp = huffmanenco(sig,dict)  % Encode the data.

->    save('file.mat','comp','dict');
->    clear all;
->    load('file.mat');

      deco = huffmandeco(comp,dict) % Decode the encoded signal.
```

But save function does not store data in low volume.
I've used dlmwrite function but the stored volume is high.
In other techniques, such as Huffman code in JPEG images, how storage is done?
As you know, the Huffman code is used in JPEG image compression.
How Huffman codes in [imwrite(mat,'mat.jpeg')] stored on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things. First, you shoudl try to create a bigger data amount. 20 is a very low number to see any difference (but you will see it).

Then, the problem is the data type. If you look at the variable called `comp` , the output of the Huffman encoding, it only contains 0s and 1s, is binary. However, in matlab, you are storing it as double, therefore using 32 bits to describe 1 bit.

try, before saving, this:

```
comp=logical(comp);
```

It should do the trick ;)

Comment: mm Please, can you reformulate that question? I dont understand it, sorry. You mean just save it? then you shouldnt change anything more in the code, just convert the comp variable to logical should suffice to save memory (note that saved archives have some header that may make them to seem bigger. If you want to see a big difference you should create a sig of 500x500 or so)